# Jenkins and Bitbucket.org webhooks 404/200 error

Tags: jenkins

I've been struggling with a webhook configuration for quite some time now and would to reach to you all for some help.

I have configured a webhook in my bitbucket repo to push to jenkins so that jenkins can receive the notification and begin a build of the project.

At first we had some networking issues, which have been corrected. i then started to get a 403 error (crumb issue). After some research i was able to add my login and API token to the webhook url and now getting a 404 error. The url cannot be found.

my webhook url looks something like this.

https://username:apitokenhere@serverwherejenkinsis.com:8080/projectname/bitbucket-hook/

404 error

But when i use the webhook URL

https://username:apitokenhere@serverwherejenkinsis.com:8080/bitbucket-hook/

I get a 200 message

Is there a config file that i need to change within jenkins to "listen" to that URL? my project is build properly with the option of "bitbucket webhook trigger" selected. I have also selected "Poll SCM" where i found some sites suggesting this option. But when i push a commit on my repo, i dont get any feedback from jenkins.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 200 is a success code, not an error code. Also, is your Jenkins server within an intranet that is not exposed to the internet, and is your Bitbucket hosted on the same intranet or is it bitbucket.org, which is hosted on the internet?

Comment: we have a jenkins server that is allowing connections through a public open port. and we use bitbucket.org.

I understand that the 200 is a successful connection, but i am wondering why the project doesnt build

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post an update as i have figured out what my problem was.

the webhook url did not need my credentials to end the bread crumb error. in fact the hook url is pretty basic.

https://serverwherejenkinsis.com:8080/bitbucket-hook/

I did not need to have the project name in the URL. ALSO, the project name in jenkins needed to  match exactly what the project name is within bitbucket.